# cannot edit in Realm Browser

Tags: edit, realm

I've read a few answers that say it's possible to edit database with Realm Browser but I can't.
I've got a base with two tables : category and specimen. The padlock top right is open. I can click on a new line, add text in fields or change text of existing fields. I go from one table to the other and back and the changes have been ignored.
I've clicked on add new object.

What am I missing?
thanks for any guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you hitting 'return' when you've finished editing a field? Additionally, there's a new test version of the Realm Browser available on its GitHub page: https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/releases/tag/0.98.3

There were some issues with text fields ignoring input commands in OS X El Capitan, but that should be resolved on the App Store version of the Browser.

In any case, please try the latest version of the Browser with those instructions, and let me know how you go!

Comment: Hittîg return (for each fiels) was the solution. So easy when you know. Thanks